# error in installing watson-machine-learning-client

Tags: python, pip, ibm-watson

On using command **pip install watson-machine-learning-client**

The terminal throws error, here is the output of terminal:

```
pip install watson-machine-learning-client
Collecting watson-machine-learning-client
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7a/ea/75de2fe2373cb3d2f0c7342b35956c4df62fce5a312cfd652a339bfb97a0/watson_machine_learning_client-1.0.357.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/l0/8fv181bn3nb6fdrnyk87j7qc0000gn/T/pip-install-oRyoix/watson-machine-learning-client/setup.py", line 30, in <module>
        with open(os.path.join(this_directory, 'README.md'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
    TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/l0/8fv181bn3nb6fdrnyk87j7qc0000gn/T/pip-install-oRyoix/watson-machine-learning-client/
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using python 2 to install the package, which is incorrectly listed as supporting python 2 on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/watson-machine-learning-client/). As you can see on the [official homepage](http://wml-api-pyclient.mybluemix.net/) (Requirements section):

> Watson Machine Learning service instance, you can create instance using this link. Only Python 3.5 or newer is supported.

You can try backporting the code to python 2, but I would rather recommend using pyhton 3 here.

Comment: How do I force to install in Python3 - I have both installed in my MAC OS.

Comment: But the command I was running might still using python2
'python -m wml.start_training_run' and it says 'No module named watson_machine_learning_client'

Comment: Adding the "3" should do the trick again: `python3 -m wml.start_training_run`